# File Download using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I tried using the below code. But it did not work.

```
public FileResult download(string path)
{
   return File(path, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(path));
}
```

My Ajax Code is:

```
function fileDownload(path) { 
    $.ajax({ 
       url: '/Home/download', 
       data: { path: path }, 
       type: 'POST', 
       async: false, 
       success: function (data) { } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Did code hit the controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is complete using window.location method.

Also You can use HTML tag for this:

```
<a href="Path" download="Filename">download me</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll generally want to map the file name to a physical path on the server, e.g. assuming the user selects the file `Foo.pdf` and all content files are in the `~/Content` folder:

```
public FileResult download(string path)
{ 
    string actualPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + path);
    return File(actualPath, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(path)); 
}
```

However, from a security viewpoint, allowing a user to directly specify a file name is dubious - you may instead want to consider other alternatives, such as a table or dictionary of available files, and force the browser to select one of the available files via key - this way malicious users can't phish for files which weren't meant to be served.

**Edit, after seeing that OP wants to Ajax**

Ajaxing the document down should work, although downloading in this way won't render the PDF - you would need to pass the document to a scriptable PDF viewer or similar.

Instead of ajaxing the document, you can instead generate a simple link, button or image which the user can click on to invoke the controller action and download the PDF:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Click to download", "download", new {path = "MyNicePDF.pdf"})
```

Comment: @HardikMansaraa you will need to qualify `Did not Work`. Rendered no file? Gave you an error? etc

Answer (score 1):

```
function DownloadAndReturnBackAttachment(linkHref) {

    $.fileDownload(linkHref, {

        successCallback: function (url) {
            gvScanDocuments.PerformCallback();
            gvScanDocuments.UnselectRows();

        },

        failCallback: function (url) {
            alert("A file download error has occurred, please try again.");
            gvScanDocuments.PerformCallback();
            gvScanDocuments.UnselectRows();

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileResult Download(string path)
{
      byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
      string fileName = "your file name";
      return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);         
}
```