# How to download a zip file in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Folder structure...
/albums/test.zip

I have a button on web page [image: Download Button]

On the button click, the test.zip that is inside albums should be downloaded.

I am not needing to build zip, on button click, the available zip should get downloaded.

Thats it.
I am using ASP.Net MVC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a file to View/Download in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)

Comment: Here's another way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27477785/84206

Comment: You could also just simply add a file link to your Zip file in your html. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/1729859

Comment: @mituw..
I will not be knowing the file name in advance..I just know that the album folder has one zip file...and that zip file is created on fly

Comment: @Chetan I see. You didn't specify that in your post. What you would need to do in your scenario then is have C# loop over all the files in your directory, and then present them as file links to your user, or open the file into a memory stream and send it back in your response headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
<a href="~/albums/test.zip">
    <img src="~/Images/download.png" alt="Download zip file." />
</a>
```

The download will start when the user clicks the image.

Comment: in my scenario, I know that albums folder has a zip file but what will be the name of the zip file that will not be knowing in advance.

Comment: @Chetan Fair enough. Consider asking a new question based on what you've learned from the answers and comments to your first question. I find that my pattern is often initial problem > question > answer > new question > answer > new question > answer that solves the initial problem.